# How does GLS or a mixed model know how to handle intermittent gaps in data with unstructured or Toeplitz covariance?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, panel-data

Let's assume I want to use linear model for repeated observations. There may be gaps at some intermittent times or visits.

When there is a gap in the mid of the study follow up, for example:

```
ID   T0   T1   T2   T3
1    OK   OK    --  OK
2    OK   OK    OK  OK
3    OK   --    --  --
4    --   --    OK  OK
```

then how the model knows how to build the covariance matrix?

For eample, for ID=1, won't the algorithm incorrectly assume that the value for T2 is the value for T3?